# ajax run mysql query and check whether mysql query was true or false?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am using the following ajax script to run my MySQL query and then only want the jquery to fade out my div and fade in another if the query returned true otherwise if the query returned false don't do anything.

Ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "include/fade_to_do_list.php",
            data: "theOption=" + $(this).attr("id"), 
            dataType: 'json',//specify data type
            success: function(data3) {
                if(data3.res.indexOf("success") >-1 ){
                    setTimeout(
                        function() {    
                            $("#to_do_list").fadeOut();
                        }, 3500
                    );

                    setTimeout(
                        function() {    
                            $("#compliance_list").fadeIn();
                        }, 500
                    );
                } 
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

PHP/MYSQL:

```
<?php 
session_start();
include 'config.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM supplier_stats WHERE complete_count = > 3 AND user_id = '{$_SESSION['id']}'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
    $query2 = "UPDATE supplier_stats SET profile_complete = 'complete' WHERE user_id = '{$_SESSION['id']}'";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);

    if($result2) {
         $return['res'] = 'success';
    } else {
} 
}

echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Please can someone show me where I am going wrong? I currently get no error and my jquery just doesnt execute. Thanks

Comment: What happens currently? Error, if so where and what is it?

Comment: @chris85 currently getting no error but my jquery doesn't execute either way no matter whether my query is true or false

Comment: It doesn't send the request or it doesn't get a response?

Comment: @I think my MySQL is not actually working in this case so it's failing and I have not told the ajax to do anything if the query fails. but I can't understand why the query isn't working

Comment: Try to simplify it and just run the PHP page by itself, turn on error reporting. Also depending on how `$_SESSION['id']` is set you might be open to SQL injections. One more thing the `else` is not required and if you aren't doing anything with it you can remove it.

Comment: @Markharris look into your equal to greater then operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_query()` always return you something. You need to `count number of affected row`.

Also problem is with equal to greater then operator it is used as `>=`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM supplier_stats WHERE complete_count >= 3 AND user_id = '{$_SESSION['id']}'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$query2 = "UPDATE supplier_stats SET profile_complete = 'complete' WHERE user_id = '{$_SESSION['id']}'";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
    $total=mysql_affected_rows();

    if($total >0) {
         $return['res'] = 'success';
    } else {

}
```